# How do I fix Postfix SASL CRAM-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure error?

Tags: postfix, sasl

I'm fairly new to Postfix - I've been using it for about the last 3 weeks. I've learned a lot by doing my own research and troubleshooting.

This one is beyond my ability to resolve.

I believe this is the part of main.cf that needs to be fixed:

```
#SASL configuration
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

Comment: _When_ do you get this error? Does it come from a client trying to connect to your Postfix server, or from Postfix itself trying to connect to _another_ server?

Comment: I'm only allowing a connection between my application server and the email server over port 25. The email server is not open to the Internet. This is when I'm trying to use a specific email account to send mail outbound from the Postfix SMTP server.